# A weird run time error in gmail addon - MessageAccessToken error

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

The add on was running finely. At some point of time , this error started showing up **only for one user**. Other users dont experience this.

```
function buildAddOn(e) { //Add on trigger function
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Home'));
  var section = CardService.newCardSection();
  section.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("hello world"));
  return card.build();
}
```

I do not have a file called Storage, though.

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u [line: 60, function: , file: Storage]"

[image]

**Update**
This has something to do with this

```
 GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(e.messageMetadata.accessToken)
```

**Update 2: Gmail UI object e is undefined**

This is not supposed to be undefined. This is an object that is provided by the Gmail UI.

```
console.log(e) //undefined
```

**Update 3**
The same addon runs perfectly for other users.

Comment: do you have access to the code in the storage file?

Comment: I do not have access to it. That might probably be stored in the google servers.

Comment: Then we probably can't help you, since we aren't affiliated with google. You should check their support

Comment: I have logged an issue here at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112159120.

Comment: are you the developer of this add-on? 
have tried the obvious like clearing cache & cookies?

Comment: Yes, I am. I don't think cache can be cleared by me.

Comment: Make your add-on fail gracefully when e is undefined. It maybe a Auth problem/ permission issue

Comment: Tried that too.

Comment: you really need to share more of the code related to the problem. there is not a lot for anyone to go on here.

Comment: @jonathon, I have updated the code based on the request.

Comment: that code doesn't reference `e`

Comment: yes. but if i log it, it returns undefined

Answer (score -2):

Empty cache and Hard reload browser this error will disappear (But keep in mind that it's not proper way to skip error for user end)

Comment: Hello Freddy thanks for your answer, however Gmail addons are server side applications. They have their storages in their servers. Hence clearing the browsers cache will be ineffective.