# Authorization broken for non-published add-ons after today's update to the Gmail Add-Ons platform

Tags: gmail-addons

We have developed a Gmail Add-On that we only use internally within our company.  Yesterday our employees were able to install the Add-On following the steps on this help doc:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/install-unpublished

Today this no longer works.  When the user clicks the "Authorize Access" button a window pops up with an error.

[image: Gmail Add-on Error]

The code for the add-on has not changed at all from yesterday to today.

For those who already had access to the Add-on, they noticed a few changes to the UI of the Add-on (ie. CardHeaders with empty strings are now collapsed).  This seems to suggest that an update was made to the Gmail Add-On platform today.  I wonder if the update today broke the authorization process for unpublished add-ons?

In my experimentation, it looks like when I install a Gmail Add-On from the G Suite Marketplace the "authorize scopes" screen is now part of the install process.  The initial "Authorization required" card for the installed Add-On no longer appears.  So it definitely seems like the authorization flow was changed, but maybe not updated for unpublished apps?  Can this be investigated please?

I should also mention we are working on creating a new add-on to publish on the G Suite Marketplace and right now it is impossible to build and test it without being able to deploy it locally.

Comment: As a follow-up, I just created a brand new add-on following the Quick Start Guide here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/quickstart and am getting the same error when following the "Deploy from manifest..." process for unpublished apps.

Comment: I found the bug - or at least a workaround.  I examined the "Authorize Access" link in the Authorization card.  It appears to be using the wrong clientID.

In my sample add-on the clientID in the link was 767331405899-b8ukfjiulu61d5i0cg30hrc9smbom6u1@developer.gserviceaccount.com

but when I looked up the actual clientID in the Google Cloud Console its listed as 767331405899-b8ukfjiulu61d5i0cg30hrc9smbom6u1.apps.googleusercontent.com

When I manually replaced the clientID in the "Authorize Access" link with the correct clientID I was able to authorize my add-on and get it working again.

Comment: It looks like this issue has been fixed now.  Thanks to the team for getting it resolved!

Comment: I ran into a similar issue , but not with authorization though. Even in my case , i did not do any code changes but got a runtime error. Seems like a problem at their end . Can refer to this post and share your opinion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51675685/a-weird-run-time-error-in-gmail-addon-messageaccesstoken-error ?